# How can I avoid first update to .on("value"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object I need to read from firebase.
I use `ref("path").once("value").then` to read the full data.

Once I have the data, I'd like to track changes to subtrees of that value. So, inside the `.then` callback, I do `.ref("path/subpath").on("value") ...`.

This all works, BUT, I get a redundant callback the first time I register for value updates on "path/subpath", as I've just read it as part of reading "path".

Is there a way to avoid this redundant read? If not, is there a "firebase way" of knowing that the data I get back is redundant? (I realize I could have versions/timestamps in my data and throw it away if I've already seen it.)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good place to use the `child_changed` event instead of `value` since you are interested on changes to the subtree.

```
.ref('path/subtree').on('child_changed', ...)
```

This notifies you when data in the subtree changes and gives you the new data value.